# The curious case of a Drupal Button

Tags: ajax, forms

The code below is used to get the word count of a field (field_body) using ajax callback. It works great and everything functions as it should, well almost.
For some reason, the click of a button is also calling the default node form submit action.

So what happens is after I update count, and suppose I don't save the content. In fact, just go to another page or refresh the page, I get something like 
Categories is required
Tags is required
Thumbnail is required....

Basically whatever I would get on form validation. It's just that the result is delayed as I am using ajax.

The problem is not with ajax, because even I comment the callback, and I click the button it tries to submit the form, when clearly it should not as executes submit callback is False.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form' || $form_id == 'q_and_a_node_form' ) {

    $form['get_word_count'] = array(
     '#type' => 'button',
     '#value' => t('Update Count'),
     '#weight' => 5,
     '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
     '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'count_words',
      ),
    );

    $form['body_words'] = array(
     '#title' => t('Words in Body'),
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#disabled' => TRUE,
     '#weight' => 5,
     '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_body_words">',
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
   $form['field_length_type']['#prefix'] = '<div id="replace_field_length_type">';
    $form['field_length_type']['#suffix'] = '</div>'; 
  }
}

function count_words($form, $form_state) {
  $str = $form['field_body']['und'][0]['value']['#value'];
  $count = preg_match_all("/\S+/", preg_replace('/(' . chr(160) .'|&nbsp;)/', ' ', strip_tags(str_replace('><', '> <', trim($str)))), $matches);
  $form['body_words']['#value'] = $count;
  if ($count < 500) {
    $form['field_length_type']['und']['#value'] = "short";
  }
  else if ($count > 500 && $count < 800 ) {
    $form['field_length_type']['und']['#value'] = "medium";
  }
  else {
    $form['field_length_type']['und']['#value'] = "long";
  }
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      ajax_command_replace("#replace_body_words", $form['body_words']),
      ajax_command_replace("#replace_field_length_type", $form['field_length_type'])
     )
   );
 }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. *Any workaround?*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this simply through JS? This way you could even show a real-time word counter. Unless you must have AJAX by design somehow or it follows up some other workflows, I think JS is by far the easiest solution. And you won't have to worry about avoiding form submittal.

Comment: This is a part of the snippet, there a few other things happening making JS difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `#type => 'button'` the submit callback is never executed, it already [receives](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#button)  a `FALSE` as default value.

Even if the `submit` callback is not executed, the `validate` callback is always executed (even on ajax posts). You can bypass this validation on a trigger element by using the `#limit_validation_errors` property.

In your case, you can set it on the `body_words` form element to only validate on this scope instead of the whole form.

```
$form['get_word_count'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Update Count'),
    '#weight' => 5,
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(
        array('body_words'),
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'count_words',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Worked in a snap!